# Google App Engine Error 0kb AppEngine-Google

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-datastore

I have a project on Google App Engine.  It has 2 separate data-stores one which holds articles and the other holds any article which is classified as a crime. (True or False)

But when I try and run my cron to move the crime articles into the "crime" data-store I receive this error:

Has anyone experienced this and how did they over come it!?

> 0kb AppEngine-Google;
>   0.1.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2011:09:47:02 -0700] "GET /place HTTP/1.1" 500 138 - "AppEngine-Google;
>   (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
>   "geo-event-maps.appspot.com" ms=1642
>   cpu_ms=801 api_cpu_ms=404
>   cpm_usd=0.022761 queue_name=__cron
>   task_name=740b13ec69de6ac36b81ff431d584a1a loading_request=1

As a result my cron fails.

Comment: I believe that message just indicates that the request handler at '/place' raised an error.  Have you tried initiating the request independently (outside of cron) to see if you could get a more detailed error message?

Comment: Expand the log entry - it should contain a stacktrace telling you exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a similar problem where my cron was crashing due to the fact that it was finding an non-ascii character and not able to process it? Try `encode('utf-8')`. My cron's work ok without needing the login URL, but it's a good tip for future :-)

Just my 2 cents worth for your question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not related to cron.  Trying to load your URL directly (http://geo-event-maps.appspot.com/place) returns an HTTP 500 error.  As an admin of the app, you should be able to run any cron job without error just by pasting the URL into a browser, so start there.

By the way, make sure to require admin access to any cron URLs.  As an unauthorized user I should have received a 401 error, not a 500.  Even if you use just one handler, you can do something like this in your app.yaml:

```
- url: /cron/.*
  script: main.py
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```